# java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data when using bootBuildImage

Tags: spring-boot, buildpack

we are trying to switch from using jib for creating the docker images to using Spring Boot built in buildpacks with bootBuildImage but are having problems in the resulting image when using JasperRerports:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontFace.<init>(SimpleFontFace.java:100)
```

it seems like there are not fonts configured in the resulting docker image - is there a way to add those?

We tried to use the `full` buildpack by configuring

```
bootBuildImage {
    buildpacks = ["paketobuildpacks/builder:full"]
```

but that throws the error

```
> Invalid buildpack reference 'paketobuildpacks/builder:full'
```

Answer (score 0):

solution was to not configure it as `buildpack` but as `runImage`

```
bootBuildImage {
    runImage = "gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run:full-cnb"
```

Comment: If you wanted to use the full builder, it would be `builder = "paketobuildpacks/builder:full"` instead of `buildpacks = ["paketobuildpacks/builder:full"]`.

Comment: thanks, in my case the problem was not in the builder but that the fonts were missing in the run image

Comment: The Paketo builder `paketobuildpacks/builder:full` bundles the `run:full-cnb` run image, so setting `builder = "paketobuildpacks/builder:full"` or setting `runImage = "gcr.io/paketo-buildpacks/run:full-cnb"` will have the same effect on the generated image.